# ___ (?) I arrived home, I put on my pyjamas

Tags: grammar

This might be an effortless question but I really can't understand a grammatical aspect of it.

> ____ I arrived home, I put on my pyjamas and I lay down on the sofa. I was exhausted and I wasn’t very hungry.

I need to figure out based on the context what word is missing. My answer is simple - *After*. Which is wrong. Since I'm not a native speaker I translate the sentence word-for-word. May be that's the problem, because I can't think in English, however, I don't see how '*after* I arrived home' can be a mistake.

The right answer is '*as soon as*', which means '*when*'. '*When*' is perfectly fine for me, but why '*after*' doesn't fit here. Is there any special grammatical rule for that type on sentences?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with ***after*** in the cited context - it's just a less common alternative to ***when***. And ***as soon as*** means essentially the same thing, but with emphasis on the fact that there was ***no delay***. The only "rule" to be learned here seems to be that an awful lot of "English tests" for non-native Anglophones on the Internet are a waste of time.

Comment: After, when, as soon as. All of these are perfectly fine.  There isn't a single correct answer here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers that's what I thought. Thanks! I even checked the BNC to make sure I'm not that ignorant to not know such basics xD

English online-tests sometimes really confuse me, but I can't find any good alternative to practice grammar. I'd be happy to get some advice!

Comment: Well, your English seems good enough that you should be able to read at least *some* books written in English without having to constantly look things up. Tip: *don't* look words up just because you don't know (exactly) what they mean; only look something up if not knowing it prevents you getting the gist of the entire containing paragraph. I also suggest you stick to books less than a century old, that you find *interesting*. And learn from things like the correcting edits @tchrist made to your question text! That's worth much more than the silly test you're actually asking about here!

Comment: The question is poorly designed if it doesn't give you narrower options. There are many things that could fill that blank

Comment: @gotube Agreed. To me "once" sounds best.

Comment: Whoever wrote the question did not really think through all sensible answers, or did not understand colloquial English.

Comment: `online-tests sometimes really confuse me,`  You need to name your source, It's the only way for anyone to know for certain whether the question was composed by a non-native speaker or not. It would be a service to warn future learners to avoid the site. I would like to see the other questions in the quiz/ exercise too just to get a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with folks in the comments, as a native speaker (American English), any of the following words or phrases would sound natural in the blank:

- After
- Once
- As soon as
- When

These all mean the same thing in this context.